# Is it possible to use cx_freeze on a python 3 project using the pip module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, cx-freeze

I am writing an installation program for a larger program I am writing, and I am using CxFreeze to convert it to an executable file, however, when I run the .exe file, it crashes with the line "import pip", and brings up (as shown below), so basically my question  is: Is it possible to use CxFreeze on an application with pip imported?

Edit:
Here are all the files I am using:

setup.py (V1):

```
from cx_Freeze import *
import os, pip
setup(name=("ARTIST"),
      version = "1",
      description = "ARTIST installation file",
      executables = [Executable("Install ARTIST.py"), Executable("C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\pip\\__init__.py")],
      )
```

This brings up the error:
[image]

setup.py (V2):

```
from cx_Freeze import *
import os, pip
setup(name=("ARTIST"),
      version = "1",
      description = "ARTIST installation file",
      executables = [Executable("Install ARTIST.py"],
      options = {"build_exe": {"packages":[pip]}}
      )
```

This brings up an error in the `setup.bat` file:
[image]

Edit:
If anyone wants to look at the website where I am publishing the larger program, here is the link:
[alaricwhitehead.wix.com/artist](http://alaricwhitehead.wix.com/artist)

Edit2:
this is the error i get when i use py2exe:
[image]

Edit3:
here is a copy of the code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uu46iynm8fr8agu/Install%20ARTIST.txt?raw=1

please note: I didn't want to have to post a link to it, but it was too long to post directly.

Comment: Could you post your setup file please

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax Look at my edit

Comment: `cx_Freeze` uses a `setup.py` file to convert a program into an executable file. This is the file I'm asking for. [How to create a cx_Freeze setup file](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html)

Comment: I think it's better to just paste in the setup.py, It is easier for people who come later to have all the relevant information right here. Dead links are not fun.

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax Look at my edit

Comment: try adding `options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["pip"]}}` somewhere in the `setup()`. Also try doing just `from cx_Freeze import *`. If this doesn't do anything I'll have to do some tests. And also sorry for the late response just kinda forgot about the question because I was a little busy when I first commented.

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax I've tried this, but i keep getiing `TypeError`s and `AtributeError`s

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax Thanks for your help so far, I would be very grateful if you could add a bounty, as this problem is stopping me from publishing my program, so any help is very gratefully received.

Comment: I've only got one program online at the moment, but this is what I want to use the installer for, to make it more efficient than the batch file I am currently using:   alaricwhitehead.wix.com/artist

Comment: The bounty has been set. Don't except an answer until your problem is completely fixed and the answer comes with a great explanation :)

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax Ok, thanks for all your help, and I will keep that in mind

Comment: Got about 15 more views, but no answers :/

Comment: I had issues with cxFreeze and ended up just using py2exe. If all else fails maybe give it a go.

Comment: @Cameron I've tried py2exe and, although it is including pip, it is giving me the error mentioned above

Comment: @sonrad10 Does the bottom answer work?

Answer (score 3):

The are two problems in your setup script. The first problem is that you specified extra modules to include in your frozen application under the `packages` option of the `build_exe` command: `packages` is for specifying which packages of your application you need to include, for the external modules (such as `pip`) you need to use `includes`. The second problem is that you need to pass to `includes` a list of strings of modules and not the module itself:

```
setup(
    name=("ARTIST"),
    version="1",
    description="ARTIST installation file",
    options={
        'build_exe': {
            'excludes': [], # list of modules to exclude
            'includes': ['pip'], # list of extra modules to include (from your virtualenv of system path),
            'packages': [], # list of packages to include in the froze executable (from your application)
        },
    },
    executables=[
        Executable(
            script='run.py', # path to the entry point of your application (i.e: run.py)
            targetName='ARTIST.exe', # name of the executable
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: You should also include an explanation of why it wasn't working or how you fixed it above the code

Comment: I thought I did actually. Probably copying and pasting from my local editor removed the explanation. I'll add it in a minute.

Comment: Yes it was that, somehow it got removed after an edit of the post, I added it back rephrasing it and hopefully clarifying the problem.

Comment: Alright thanks I'm going to look into it. And I will reward you with the bounty when the OP tests your answer.

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax @Daniele Pantaleone I have tried this answer, and am still getting the same error (I.e: can't find the pip module), I have also tried pointing the `includes` option to the containing folder, the module pip and various other strategies, but it keeps failing when i run the exe. So I think that, for the moment at least, the answer to my question is no, i'll see if i can contact the developers of cxfreeze soon, to see if its anything they can incorporate. Delerious Syntax, you can decide if this answer deserves the bounty or not, as it did help answer the question, if not directly

Comment: @sonrad10 Yeah he'll receive the bounty as bounties are nonrefundable and must go to someone or bounty will be lost. Tomorrow the bounty ends as well.

Comment: @sonrad10 no problem, love to help. Just wish you could've found something that works. It is definitely possible just gotta know how.

Comment: Could you share the python script you are trying to freeze? Else I can't tell why it isn't working because the setup script should be "ok"

Comment: @DanielePantaleone I have posted the code that i want to freeze. Sorry about the late response, i've only just got the notification

Comment: You should always post also the imports since I don't know where things come from

Comment: @DanielePantaleone His entire program is on his dropbox link.

Comment: Just tried and to me it works. Running `python setup.py build_exe` generated the executable file as expected.

Comment: @DanielePantaleone Have you tried running the exe? Could be a version specific problem or just a file you must include manually

Comment: @DanielePantaleone I went ahead and gave you the bounty for your time.

Comment: Ok, now I can see the problem. I'm afraid I don't have a solution for this. It seems that the `user_site` variable in `pip/locations.py` is not getting initialized by the `site` module: `user_site = site.USER_SITE`. In the site module there is a comment stating that such variables are supposed to be initialized when the main is run, so "theoretically" it should not work also when running your program from python sources. Else I'm missing something but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @DanielePantaleone ok, thanks for your help anyway, it seems that since this is/almost is impossible to do, next time I have a free moment, I'll try another way round this (ie: download a .bat file containing the pip commands and run that).